# How do I orderbychild and archive latest message to appear on top?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to order new items to appear on top but it seems I am not able to reach the receiver id in order for me to add it to the query , My current query does not archive the desired result since nothing changes on the recyclerview whenever i run the app.

please help

this is my database structure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLMx3.png)

this is my reference

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PcI2.png)

Here is my query

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YixKA.png)

Comment: All this is happening on on a fragment and i do to how how to get the receivers Id